# Angularjs- How to see if a directive is active/in the dom or not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I am writing an app with Ionic v1 and Angular v1.5.

I am using this 3rd party library in my project:
https://github.com/djett41/ionic-content-banner

It is directive-based. I have a problem in my code where if I have more than one error than 2 banners show. I want to check if there is already a banner before showing a new one.

```
$ionicContentBanner.show({
    text: data,
    type: type,
    interval: 3000,
    transition: 'vertical'
});
```

https://github.com/djett41/ionic-content-banner/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

I have never used ionic, but if I take a look the code of the service [$ionicContentBanner](https://github.com/djett41/ionic-content-banner/blob/master/js/ionic.content.banner.service.js#L37)
In the getActiveView it is doing something like you want, in the line 37 it checks the active 'candidate' views:

```
var views = body.querySelectorAll('ion-view[nav-view="active"]');
```

Also, take a look the next if, it's interesting...

So, you can use that sentence to be sure that there aren't another views, or, easily, when you call the $ionicContentBanner.show method you can set a $rootScope variable, something like:

```
$rootScope.isBannerShowed = true;
```

And only call $ionicContentBanner.show when false